# I accidentally downloaded PyCharm with Python 3. How can I change it to Python 2?

Tags: python, pycharm

I accidentally downloaded PyCharm and chose Python 3 when I meant to choose Python 2.7. How can I change it to Python 2.7?

Comment: download again with python2?

Comment: If possible, just use Python 3 :)

Answer (score 4):

Steps:

1. Make sure you have Python2 installed. [Download](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and install if needed.
2. File -> Default Settings -> Project interpreter: choose Python2.7

If it's not listed, add it.

See [configuring python interpreter](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.ht%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bml) on the PyCharm website.